# Create dynamic climbing method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, vector, raycasting

I would like to understand how to create a script to climb objects of different heights like in this video [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkrV3jk8cp8).
I know you have to use LayerMask to understand if you are in front of an object, but I don't understand the script that brings the character from below to above the object or on the other side (if it is a wall to climb over) .
For a ladder, I thought I'd put "gravity = false" and "transform.up * Input vertical" to go up or down. But to position yourself above a wall in this way, what script do it's used?
And how does the same animation be usable on walls of different heights as in the video ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an animator, setup your animations in your state machine, in the animator click ‘apply root motion’ and your animation will apply to your character position.

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example? in short, if I want my character to rise above a cube, I can activate the "climb over" function when it is close to the cube to make it rise above, but what does it consist of at the script level? ... the animation itself even if I insert it how can I apply it to cubes of different sizes?

Comment: in your state machine set conditions and in your script you set the values or triggers to your animator, for cubes of different sizes there is no easily explanation, the simplest would be different climbing animations for different sizes